# Self join and inner join to remove duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle

I am stuck on this and I am relatively new to SQL.

Here is the question we were given:

> List the productname and vendorid for all products that we have
>   purchased from more than one vendor (Hint: you’ll need a Self-Join and
>   an additional INNER JOIN to solve, don't forget to remove any
>   duplicates!!)

Here is a screenshot of tables we are working with:

[image]

Here is what I have.....I know it is wrong. It works to a degree, just not exactly how the prof wants it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT productname, product_vendors.vendorid 
FROM products INNER JOIN Product_Vendors
ON products.PRODUCTNUMBER = PRODUCT_VENDORS.PRODUCTNUMBER
INNER JOIN vendors ON Product_Vendors.VENDORID = vendors.VENDORID
ORDER BY products.PRODUCTNAME;
```

Expected output provided the prof:

[image]

Comment: Specify sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: I'd probably do a GROUP BY with COUNT().

Comment: Hi Mike, we are only supposed to use INNER JOIN for this exercise.

Comment: No need at all for a LEFT JOIN here.

Comment: inner join same table twice, make sure different vendors!

Comment: @jarlh the information given is minimal and this is a database that was given to us, so we didn't actually build it. Based on his question, it is my assumption that it is ONLY duplicates

Comment: @BobMcEnroe First off, I would start by writing a query to find the productnumber rows in product_vendor that have more than one vendorid. You can do this using `GROUP BY`, `COUNT(*)` (or maybe `COUNT(DISTINCT vendorid)` if you can have the same vendorid repeated in different rows for the same productnumber). Once you have that, you can then use that to join back to the product and product_vendor tables to get the productnames and vendorids. (for bonus points, look up the analytic COUNT function; using this instead of the aggregate COUNT would negate the need for the self-join).

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @jarlh that additional information would be helpful- i.e. are there triplicates in the data or just duplicates, etc.

That said, this should get your started

```
SELECT
    c.productname   AS 'Product'
    ,a.vendorid     AS 'Vendor1'
    ,b.vendorid     AS 'Vendor2'

FROM
    product_vendors AS a
JOIN 
    product_vendors AS b
        ON 
        a.productnumber = b.productnumber
        AND a.vendorid <> b.vendorid
JOIN
    dbo.products AS c
        ON
        a.productnumber = c.productnumber
```

This will limit the population of 'Product Vendors' just to products with unmatching vendors.
From there you are joining to products to pull back product name.

Also- work on coding format, clean code makes the dream work :)

Comment: Would have been even better with appropriate alias names, e.g. `p` for products and `v1`and `v2` for the product vendors.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem is usually to count vendors per product with `COUNT OVER` and only stick with products with more than one. Simply:

```
select productname, vendorid
from
(
  select 
    p.productname, 
    pv.vendorid, 
    count(*) over (partition by product) as cnt
  from products p
  join product_vendors pv using (productnumber)
)
where cnt > 1;
```

If this shall be done without window functions, then one option is to aggregate product_vendors and use this result:

```
select p.productname, pv.vendorid
from
(
  select productid 
  from product_vendors
  group by productname
  having count(*) > 1
) px
join products p using (productid)
join product_vendors pv using (productid);
```

or check whether exists another vendor for the product:

```
select 
  p.productname, 
  pv.vendorid, 
  count(*) over (partition by product) as cnt
from products p
join product_vendors pv on pv.productnumber = p.productnumber
where exists
(
  select *
  from product_vendors other
  where other.productnumber = pv.productnumber
  and other.vendorid <> pv.vendorid
);
```

In neither of these approaches I see the need to eliminate duplicates, as there should be one row per product in `products` and one row per product and vendor in `product_vendors`. So I guess what your prof was thinking of is:

```
select distinct
  p.productname, 
  pv.vendorid
from products p
join product_vendors pv on pv.productnumber = p.productnumber
join product_vendors other on other.productnumber = pv.productnumber
                           and other.vendorid <> pv.vendorid
```

This, however, is an approach I don't recommend. You'd combine all vendors for a product (e.g. with 10 vendors for one product you already have 45 combinations for that product only, if I'm not mistaken). So you'd create a large intermediate result only to dismiss most of it with `DISTINCT` later. Don't do that. Remember: `SELECT DISTINCT` is often an indicator for a poorly written query (i.e. unnecessary joins leading to too many combinations you are not actually interested in).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.name AS product, v.id
FROM products p 
     INNER JOIN product_vendors pv ON p.id = pv.productid
     INNER JOIN product_vendors pv2 ON pv.productid = pv2.productid AND pv.vendorid != pv2.vendorid 
     INNER JOIN vendors v ON v.id = pv.vendorid
ORDER BY p.name
```

Comment: Please add description to your answer. What are your code do